# APA citation style for different authors with the same last name

Tags: apa

Let's assume I have a citation list that includes the three different hypothetical authors A. Miller, B. Miller, and C. Miller (besides Y. Young, S. Stevens, and Z. Zona):

> Miller, A., & Young, Y. (2001)
>
> Miller, B., & Stevens, S. (2002)
>
> Stevens, S., & Miller, B. (2003)
>
> Zona, Z., & Miller, C. (2004)

Is the following the correct APA in-text citation style?

> A. Miller & Young, 2001
>
> B. Miller & Stevens, 2002
>
> Stevens & Miller, 2003
>
> Zona & Miller, 2004

Or would initials be also included for second authors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version of my answer was wrong. Here is the relevant section from the APA Publication Manual:

> **6.14 Authors With the Same Surname**
>
> If a reference list includes publications by two or more primary
> authors with the same surname, include the first author's initials in
> all text citations, even if the year of publication differs. Initials
> help the reader to avoid confusion within the text and to locate the
> entry in the list of references (see section 6.25 for the order of
> appearance in the reference list).
>
> *References:*
>
> Light, I. (2006). *Deflecting immigration: Networks, markets, and regulation in Los Angeles.* New York, NY: Russell Sage Foundation.
>
> Light, M. A., & Light, I. H. (2008). The geographic expansion of Mexican immigration in the United States and its implications for local law enforcement. *Law Enforcement Executive Forum Journal*, *8*, 73-82.
>
> *Text Cites:*
>
> Among studies, we review M. A. Light and Light (2008) and I. Light
> (2006).

From this it would follow that your in-text citation examples are correct. Initials are only included for the first, but not for the second authors.

---

*Note.*

Since the proper formatting of the reference list is not technically possible on this site, I'll attach a screenshot from the APA Manual:

[image: screenshot of the citation from the APA manual]

Comment: Please use plain text instead of images of text.